# How to change the background color of the clicked bar in Charts.js

Tags: chart.js

Before upgrading to Chart.js 4.x, I used custom attribute on element to override the background color for active bar, like described here : [Highlight last clicked bar in ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261835/highlight-last-clicked-bar-in-chartjs)

It does not work anymore with 4.x version as explained here : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#customizability but I don't understand how to achieve the same thing.

I have tried to change the element backgroundColor option, but it does not seems to be working :(